# Google Plus doesn't show article image, just shows title and article link

Tags: schema, google-plus, facebook-opengraph, schema.org

I am trying to share a post from my website(blog) onto Google plus but it isn't showing the featured image of the article, instead it is just showing the title and link of the article. I have microdata and also "og" tags for my page. When tested using Google Structured data testing tool, it is showing all good. I expect to get some help here. ﻿If I am trying to share the home page, it is showing an image, however if I am trying to share any post from the website, it is not showing any image. Please help, let me know if you need any more info, would be happy to provide.

[One of post's from website](http://top10grocerysecrets.com/2015-07-21-top-10-functional-foods-relieving-inflammation.html)

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: A good place to start is the `og:image` path results in a 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

The `og:image` meta tag is being used by google plus rather than the image property within your http://schema.org/BlogPosting -as @abraham pointed out this is a broken link, it should go to `http://top10grocerysecrets.com/Top-10-foods-for-releiving-inflammation.jpg` - currently it includes `/wp-content/uploads/sites/17/2015/07/` which isn't part of the image's path.

In the structured data it is valid, but not *correct*: BlogPosting has an image set but *without a full path* which may be why it gets ignored: the source should begin `http://` etc. This is also needed if you want the image to appear in the google search results preview.

The WebPage element does not have an image set: only the BlogPosting does. Consider setting the same `image` property using a meta tag inside the WebPage element if fixing the BlogPosting image's path does not resolve the structured data issue, e.g.

```
<meta itemprop="image" content="http://top10grocerysecrets.com/Top-10-foods-for-releiving-inflammation.jpg" nt-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="Print" />
```

In the structured data there are two unrelated mistake

- the BlogPosting has `author` set to a link with fixed IP address `http://162.244.66.231/top10grocerysecrets/author/cyoung` this will reduce the chance of it connecting the blog with C Young's profile on the website.
- the file name `http://top10grocerysecrets.com/Top-10-foods-for-releiving-inflammation.jpg` has 'releiving' in it, which is not the spelling used in the text on the image itself. This doesn't matter a great deal.